# Add JSON objects to a list

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I have a function that generates a report from Excel file. 
For now, it work like:

```
import json

def get_dic_from_two_lists(keys, values):
    return { keys[i] : values[i] for i in range(len(keys)) }

def report(items):
    for i in range(items):
        dict_keys = ['name', 'age']
        dict_values = ['n', 'a']
        data = get_dic_from_two_lists(dict_keys, dict_values)
        report = json.dumps(data)
        print(report)
report(5)
```

Where items is number of reports to generate.
It works good, but I need to append results into a list and separate JSON objects with a comma and, moreover, write everything to a file. Any good way to do it? `append()` function just doesn't seem to work out.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you fix the indentation and punctuation in your code so that it doesn't produce a syntax error?

Comment: Sure, already done.

Comment: post your desired output to be on same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all your report objects in the list and then convert it to JSON at once:

```
import json

def get_dic_from_two_lists(keys, values):
    return { keys[i] : values[i] for i in range(len(keys)) }

def report(items):
    data_list = []
    for i in range(items):
        dict_keys = ['name', 'age']
        dict_values = ['n', 'a']
        data = get_dic_from_two_lists(dict_keys, dict_values)
        data_list.append(data)

    reports = json.dumps(data_list)
    print(reports)

report(5)
```

Comment: Pure gold, understood my mistake. Thanks!